# How to convert HQL to list of entities using Hibernate transformers

Tags: java, hibernate

I have following Entity class mapped to tables.

```
@Entity
class User{
      String name;
      String email;
      Date dob;

      Department dept;

      //Other fields
}

@Entity
class Department{
    String deptName;
    String deptHead;
    //Other fields
}
```

I am writing following HQL query to get List of ONLY name and email, deptName of all Users.

```
Stringn str="SELECT e.name as name, e.email as email, e.deptName as deptName FROM User e";
Query query = session.createQuery(str)
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class));;

list=query.list();
```

This throws an exception while tranforming results.

```
Could not find setter for deptname on class pkg.User
```

This query works perfect if I dont put deptName.

Is there any way to get a List of Type Users with query.

```
List<User>
```

Comment: Your query isn't valid: User doesn't have any deptName field. Why do you make your own life complicated? Why not just use `select u from User u`?

Comment: @JBNizet If I has to use this query then it will fetch all properties of user as well as dept. I just dont want that. I need projection on three specific fields.

Comment: Then define a class that has those fields, and only those fields. Don't pretend you get an attached User entity when all you get is three fields. But you're probably prematurely optimizing. If your database is so small that you can get **all** the users from a query, then fetching a few more fields than necessary won't make a noticeable difference.

Comment: @JBNizet: My DB is not small. I just dont want to load this forum with unnecessary details. I know I can create a new view object with there properties.

Comment: Then just do it. It's much cleaner than trying to pretend your query returns users, since it doesn't.

Comment: My question is: Is there any way to achieve this without adding  new view objects ?

Comment: Of course there is a way: 1. make the query valid, 2. make sure there is a setter for each field returned by the query. But you **should not** do that.